# Silverlight C# - ComponentOne Spellchecker not loading dictionary

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, reference, componentone

This may be a long shot, but I'm using ComponentOne's Spellchecker control for Silverlight. I made a test project, added a plain textbox and a button to it, added the references to the C1.Silverlight and C1.Silverlight.SpellChecker bits, and added the dictionary file to my project.

In the code, I called up the spellchecker on button1's click event and it worked SPLENDIDLY. The spellchecker dialog shows up, and works exactly as it should.

Since that test was successful, I then tried to implement this into my existing project. I've had no success for absolutely NO reason that I can determine, since I used the EXACT SAME code.

Here's the code I use to call the component:

```
using C1.Silverlight;
using C1.Silverlight.SpellChecker;
using C1.Silverlight.Resources;

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    C1SpellChecker spellChecker = new C1SpellChecker();


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        spellChecker.MainDictionary.LoadAsync("C1Spell_en-US.dct");

    }

    private void btnSpelling_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dlg = new C1SpellDialog();
        spellChecker.CheckControlAsync(txtArticle, false, dlg);
    }
```

The references to `C1.Silverlight` and `C1.Silverlight.Spellchecker` are added to this project as well, and the dictionary as been added in the same fashion as well. The issue seems to be that for whatever reason the dictionary is not loading, because the spellChecker.Enabled method returns whether or not the main dictionary has been loaded. If I call `MessageBox.Show("SpellChecker Enabled = " + spellChecker.Enabled.ToString());` it shows false, even though the call to load the dictionary is there (as you can see).

**What would cause the dictionary to not load? Have I added it to my project incorrectly somehow?**

**EDIT**: I suspect that I have added the dictionary to the project incorrectly, because the [ComponentOne reference](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1silverlight/default.htm?turl=XMLDocuments/Ref/html/M_C1_Silverlight_SpellChecker_SpellDictionaryBase_LoadAsync_1_72eac341.htm) states:

> If C1SpellChecker cannot find the
>   spelling dictionary, it will not throw
>   any exceptions. The Enabled property
>   will be set to false and the component
>   will not be able to spell-check any
>   text.

I just don't know what's wrong though because it was added in the same way that it was in the test project (Right clicked on the project.web->Add->Existing Item)

As always, thank you!

-Sootah

Comment: are you sure that C1Spell_en-US.dct is even available to the spellchechecker to load.

Comment: I'm not sure that it was added properly, or if I need to change the path to it, but don't know how test to see if it's avail, what properties to check, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post is duplicated in our forum as well, but will answer first here. Please try this:

1) Try to access the .dct file using your browser. If you cannot see it, it's probably because your web server is not serving that type of files. You need ton configure the web server to allow it.

2) verify the URL you are using is correct.http://helpcentral.componentone.com/CS/silverlight_161/f/78/p/86955/241328.aspx#241328

3) Check you are setting everything correctly: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/CS/silverlight_161/f/78/p/81924/227790.aspx#227790

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like the main issue was that my project started running from file:// instead of localhost:// for whatever reason. After setting up the URI as shown in your example (the event handler code was also quite handy, BTW) and running it from the Development Server it works beautifully.

I do, however, want it to be able to run from the file:// bit as well, since this particular app is actually going to be distributed directly to the users instead of running off of a webserver. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could add the dictionary to the Silverlight app as an embedded resource and then load it using this code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // load C1SpellChecker dictionary from embedded resource
        var asm = this.GetType().Assembly;
        foreach (var res in asm.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (res.EndsWith(".dct"))
            {
                using (var s = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(res))
                {
                    sc.MainDictionary.Load(s);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 10 Years Later, this came in handy @Bernardo